# Avoid confusing multiple instances of vscode with icons

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using multiple instances of visual studio code it is sometimes difficult to pick out which instance belongs to which project. Is there a solution, like having project specific icons?

If it is platform dependent i'm specifically interested in linux/ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Not project specific but under Linux you can create new `.desktop` files under `/usr/share/applications` by copying the original one and changing icons. You can then choose what project to open in each instance. Depending on your Desktop environment it might not change the icons in your task bar though...